# I need Linux (eGPU, Cuda, Tensorflow) on my MacBook Pro

Tags: 18.04, 19.10, macbook-pro

Im at the end of my wits. Im having an MacBook Pro 2018 15" and all I want to do is just to install ubuntu and its a nightmare.

I want to use macOS when im on the go, at university etc and when im come I want to plug in my mouse, keyboard, eGPU and external SSD and boot onto ubuntu that is installed on the SSD and do my ML stuff.
I have to use Ubuntu since macOS doesn't have any Nvidia RTX drivers, and tensorflow for Mac does not support GPU for some strange reason.

Here is what I did:

I booted into recovery and turned off secure boot and also executed the csrutil disable command. After that I can boot from the USB and im trying to install it onto an external SSD via usb 3.0.

I tried that on my iMac and it wiped my boot partition and I had to reinstall everything.

When im installing it on my MacBook Pro im getting two error messages:

[Executing 'grub-install/dev/sda' failed this is a fatal error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smNW2.jpg)

[The 'grub-efi-amd64-signed' packaged failed to install into target /. Without the GRUB boot loader, the installed system will not boot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MuBHX.jpg)

The weird thing is I was able to install PopOS but the wifi chip, keyboard and touchpad don't work and I didnt manage to install the Nvidia drivers either.

I really need some help im about to throw the towel down or my MacBook out of the window. PLEASE HELP ME im losing my mind.

Comment: Looks like launchpad bugs 1173457,1396379,1702335 affect Macs too.  The bootloaders go to the EFI of sda instead of where you tell them.  Have an EFI partition on the SDD, copy the hdd's /EFI/ubuntu to SDD, and set up /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi (and reset the backup copy on HDD to original).

Comment: I just wiped the SSD again. Could you please write me a step by step instruction what to do to get it running? im not fully understanding what and how to do it. Please I hope you can take your time to do a step by step guide how to setup EFI partition, bootx64.efi etc

Comment: See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI, Nothing special about using a Mac as far as I know.  The install (with all the bootloaders going to HDD), should actually boot grub as long as the SDD is attached, and without the SDD, the EFI boot menu (on a MAC?) should still allow you to directly boot MAC. Lots written on UEFI setup here, scan the answers and tutorials/howtos. Just did an effortless eGPU setup on an old laptop, no problems at all.